# No NIBs, UIWindow Not Filling Screen, iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7

I'm avoiding using NIBs completely. I'm getting problems on iOS 7.1, but not on iOS 8.x.

**iOS 7 vs. iOS 8**

[image: iOS 7]   [image: iOS 8]

The code looks like this in the `UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>`

```
- (void) setupViewController {
    CGRect frame = UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds;
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    self.window.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor; // viewController's view is green
    ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.window.bounds];
    viewController.view = view;
    self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [self setupViewController];
    return YES;
}
```

I've also tried some methods dealing with iOS 8, but even settings the `UIWindow` `frame` to `5000, 5000` produces the same results.

[I've seen a number of related questions and tried out the suggestions, but to no avail, including flipping the bounds if it's iOS 8, etc. etc.]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have a launch image for the 4-inch screen, so the iPhone 5s is treating this app as a 3.5-inch app (iPhone 4) and letterboxing it.

Comment: Launch images work differently on iOS 7 and iOS 8, and that's the problem. You must satisfy the rules for both.

Comment: So merely switching the Launch Images Source to an "Asset Catalog" solved the problem, as you suggested. All the launch images are blank, but it still works. Thanks for all you do, man, it's a great help!

Comment: Same problem here while migrating an old project to > iOS 12. Couldn't get the app window fullscreen. By just adding an empty "Launch screen interface file base name" to info.plist solved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: @Raf Nice! It's great that you even found this question-and-answer.